# PHP PDO sqlsrv large result set inconsistency

Tags: php, pdo, sqlsrv

I am using PDO to execute a query for which I am expecting ~500K results. This is my query:

```
SELECT Email FROM mytable WHERE flag = 1
```

When I run the query in Microsoft SQL Server management Studio I consistently get 544838 results. I wanted to write a small script in PHP that would fetch these results for me. My original implementation used `fetchAll()`, but this was exhausting the memory available to php, so I decided to fetch the results one at a time like so:

```
$q = <<<QUERY                                                                                           
SELECT Email FROM mytable WHERE flag = 1                                                      
QUERY;

$stmt = $conn->prepare($q);
$stmt->execute();

$c = 0;
while ($email = $stmt->fetch()[0]) {
    echo $email."   $c\n";
    $c++;
}
```

but each time I run the query, I get a different number of results! Typical results are:

```
445664
445836
445979
```

The number of results seems to be short 100K +/- 200 ish. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to get the exact count with `SELECT COUNT(Email) FROM mytable WHERE flag = 1` ? What does it say when you launch it multiple times ? Have you noticed the numbers you put are growing ? Is it a production database ?

Comment: @Daishi when I use COUNT, I do indeed get the correct number. It remains consistent no matter how many times I check as well. No, it is not a production database.

Comment: What happens if you don't print every row and just display `$c` once at the end? Is your server configured in such a way that a program errors gets displayed on screen and/or logged? What HTTP status code can you see in the browser *Network* pane?

Comment: How about using `while ($email = $stmt->fetch()) {` and echoing `$email[0]`?

Comment: @alalp That did the trick! ...but why? Feel free to add an answer to the question so I can accept it.

Comment: @sigsegv if any of the row contains a value that equals to a boolean `false` the while loop will exit. And as long as you don't specify an `ORDER BY`, the order of the rows may be inconsistent from one query to another, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch()` method fetches one row at a time from current result set. `$stmt->fetch()[0]` is the first column of the current row.

Your sql query has no ordering and can have some null or empty values (probably).

Since you are controlling this column value in while loop, if the current row's first value is null, it will exit from the loop.

Therefore, you should control only `fetch()`, not `fetch()[0]` or something like that.

Also, inside the while loop, use `sqlsrv_get_field()` to access the columns by index.

```
$c = 0;
while ($stmt->fetch()) { // You may want to control errors
   $email = sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, 0); // get first column value
   // $email can be false on errors

   echo $email . "   $c\n";
   $c++;
}
```

[sqlsrv_fetch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-fetch)